# xcode 4.2 Message from Analyze tool

Tags: xcode, memory-leaks

Little confused about the message from Analyze command in Xcode 4.2.  It complains about the instance variable activityView.

[image]

Analyze tool complains on [self startRefresh:NULL] line about potential leak of activityView.

1. activityView is an instance variable, and is synthesized
2. I am releasing activityView in dealloc()
3. Per my understanding, when the setter is used (implicitly via self.activityView), the previous value is released, right?

So, I how should I read the warning from the Analyze tool?  Or what changes do I need?

Thx.

Comment: try both solution given in my answer, and see how analyser reacts.

Comment: I assume you meant to say that activityView is a @property, not just an instance variable, since you also say it is synthesized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the @property has the retain attribute, the setter will retain this new activity view, so you are still responsible for the +1 count from the alloc/init.

So you can do something like this:

```
self.activityView = [[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite] autorelease];
```

Just autorelease the new instance to balance out the alloc/init.

The analyzer isn't warning you about the previous value of activityView. It's warning you about the new instance, which effectively has a +2 retain count after your alloc/init and the @property (retain).